# Replacing Body with Stream not sending full body

Tags: php, slim

We have a requirement from an integration partner to send encrypted bodies to the front-end. I am currently testing with XOR ciphering before fully implementing encryption. The issue that I am running into is that when I replace the response body with a new stream, I only get a partial response back to the front end. I tested sending a generic response back to see if it was somewhere in the encoding, but I am getting the same result.

Here is the setup for creating the new stream

```
    $fiveMBs = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    $stream = fopen("php://temp/maxmemory:$fiveMBs", 'r+');
    $body = trim($resp->getBody());
    fwrite($stream, base64_encode($this->xor($body, $key)));
    rewind($stream);
    $resp = $resp->withBody(new Body($stream));
    return $resp;
```

I am using the temp file for writing the stream as a test, I started by using memory, but switched to rule that out as the issue.

Here is the response I am getting:

```
// Encoded
SUZDF1RCQRUPCBF3UFldE1dDSAZHSBBBClxSBlVoTVxoBAd

// Decoded
{"status":"Activated","linked_to_ac
```

EDIT: I tested sending the encoded body as a header to test the XOR cipher and I am getting the full response in the header. It looks like it is specific to the stream because if I send `stream_get_contents($stream)` in the header, I am only getting the partial response.

Also, I have replaced `\Slim\Http\Body` with `\Slim\Http\Stream` and the results are exactly the same

Comment: Instead of `Body`, can you try `\Slim\Http\Stream`

Comment: @ChrisHaas switching to Stream produces the same results